# Complex integral of $\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2 -3z +1} $

Tags: complex-integration

I have to calculate $\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2 -3z +1} =
 \int_0^1 \frac{2 i \pi e^{2 i \pi  t}\mathrm{d}t}{(e^{2 i \pi  t})^2 -3e^{2 i \pi  t} +1}=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ i e^{i \theta}\mathrm{d}\theta}{(e^{i \theta})^2 -3e^{i \theta} +1}$  and I found a $tanh^{-1}$ as antiderivative and I found zero as final result. But Wolfram Alpha find $-\frac{2 i \pi}{\sqrt{5}}$ as final result. I really don't understand where my mistake could be. Can you help me?

Comment: Residue theorem?

Comment: why is the integral valued from 0 to 1? antiderivatives for a closed contour? Am I understanding the notation correcctly?

Comment: Yes it is a closed contour. Maybe using $e^{i\theta}$ and integrating between $0$ and $2\pi$ is clearer?

Comment: I can't use residue theorem

Comment: Sorry, my bad I couldn't see the exponents you used properly. Why can't you use residue theorem? Cauchy integral formula? Have you plotted integration contour and singularities enclosed (if any)? If not, cauchy goursat theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's $r1=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $r2=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ be the roots of $z^2 -3z +1$, then we have
\begin{align*}
    \int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2 -3z +1} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{1}{z-r1}\mathrm{d}z - \int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{1}{z-r2}\mathrm{d}z \right)
 \end{align*}

But $r2=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}>1$ so $r2 \notin D(0,1)$ then $\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{1}{z-r2}\mathrm{d}z=0$

Let's calculate $\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{1}{z-r1}\mathrm{d}z$ : we set $g(z)=1$, from integral Cauchy formula, we get

\begin{align*}
&g(r1) =\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{g(z)}{z-r1}\mathrm{d}z\\
\iff & 1 = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{g(z)}{z-r1}\mathrm{d}z\\
\iff  &\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{g(z)}{z-r1}\mathrm{d}z = 2 \pi i\\
\iff  &\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{1}{z-r1}\mathrm{d}z = 2 \pi i\\
\end{align*}

We deduce

$$ \int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2 -3z +1}  = \frac{-2 \pi i}{\sqrt{5}} $$